# iOS 10 custome remote notifications sound not playing the whole file length

Tags: ios, ios10

I am aware of the bug in iOS 10 that will prevent custom remote notifications sound from playing.  The current solution seemed to be restart the device.  That seemed to temporary fix.  But this problem will reoccur again.

But my problem is that when it did play the custom sound, it did not play the whole file (30 seconds or less).  It only plays 2-3 seconds and the notification view disappears.

It works fine under iOS 9.

Have you encountered this issue?  Any suggestions?